# Mark items far away from each other as grouped (connected)

Tags: icons, lists, indicator, grouped-list, connection

I have a tree structure with items from different trees that I need to "group" (or really, mark as grouped).

Like so:

[image]

It is mandatory for the user to select a few of these items to carry on to the next step. Some items are mandatory, like item 1 in group 1, item 3 in group 2 and items 4 and 8 in group 3. And then there are items that the user can chose between, but one of them is still mandatory.  Like the can chose item 3 in group 1 OR item 2 in group three have to be selected and item 1 in group 2 OR item 3 in group 3.

How to make this visually clear to the user?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. Are you asking the user to create and define the contents of a new Group?

Answer (score 1):

Step wise wizard with clear segregated choices.
When user moves to next step, load related choices then.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't show the groups, show the steps. Step 1(or 2) fill in the required things.

Step 2(or 1) pick between the OR selections.

Step 3, select optional items.

Answer (score 0):

One option you may try is the following :

- Use selected disabled checkboxes for the mandatory items
- For each group of items, that at least one of them must be selected, use a hallow geometrical shape (circle, triangle, square etc). Use different colors for each shape.
- Place the shape next to each item accordingly
- Initially all items are unselected (except from the mandatory)
- When an item belonging to a group of items that at least one of them must be selected, change the shape from hallow to filled in all items of the group.
- You have to give detailed instructions to users how this works

At the example below :
Mandatory items are : Group 1 item 3, Group 2 item 1, Group 3 item 7

at lest one groups are : triangle group, square group, circle group

[image]